# Can't send any email from Magento 2.0 admin panel

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, email

I was tried to send custom email through admin panel but
Not even send email while clicking forget password at admin panel.

So how can i solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to setup new module from below github link.

[Gmail SMTP Mail link for magento 2](https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmailsmtpapp)

Download zip from github link keep it inside **app/code/MagePal/GmailSmtpApp** folder

After Install module,

Run command,

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Remove var folder content from root.

Go To admin panel,

> Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System

***Go To Gmail/Google SMTP Pro tab,***

**Set Username as your google email id and Password as your email password.**

Comment: I can send email from store but i can't  send any email from admin panel ,so is the above solution for that ?

Comment: This is working for me for front and backend both